# Jquery: Get text of element inside $(this)

Tags: jquery

here's a snippet of jquery code that works for me:

```
   onSelect: function() {
        var thevalue = $(this).val();
        jQuery('#input').val(thevalue);
    }
```

The markup is like this: There's a text , 
and then a list of auto-suggested items

```
<ul class="ac_results">
<li><span class="suggested">
  <span class="ac_matched">(matched text)</span>
 (rest of auto-suggested text)</span>
<div class="count">(number)</div>
 </li>
repeat..
repeat...
etc...
</ul>
```

This markup/jQUery combo WORKS, but returns the full string with the number into the input field. I want to leave out that number, so I did:

```
   onSelect: function() {
        var thevalue = $(this).find(".suggested").text();
        jQuery('#input').val(thevalue);
    }
```

It returns empty.

the number could be anything, and the span COULD contain numbers, so I'm weary of just filtering out numbers.

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Answer (score 0):

You don't post your HTML, but the obvious suspicion is that

```
$(this).find(".suggested")
```

is not returning any elements. Always ensure your chain has elements on the stack in jQuery before selecting other things.

This is easily tested:

```
alert($(this).find(".suggested").length);
```

If you get `0`, it's not matching anything. If you get no alert at all, the entire function isn't running.

Comment: I get 0, it's not matching anything. But, as I said, it works when I just use $(this).val();

Comment: It is not easy to find out what the onSelect event is a response of. What can be noted is that find only finds child element and not the element itself. div.find('.foo') will in other words only find child elements (of any depth) to div, but not div itself.

Comment: If you're getting 0 then your chain has no elements - that right there is the problem that needs addressing.